# copy item from csv, script copies also other folders

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am trying to create a script that copies folders from one location to another. I am accessing the csv file where I have headers "Name and Letter". The issue is that not only users in CSV are copied but also the whole active folder is copied to Inactive. How can this be solved? I want to copy only users in the csv file. 
Thanks

```
$folder = "D:\Test\users\Active"
$destination = "D:\Test\users\Inactive"
$file = Import-Csv 'D:\Test\Test1.csv' -Delimiter ';'

$file | foreach { 
Copy-Item "$folder\$($_.Letter)\$($_.Name)" -Destination "$destination\$($_.Letter)" -recurse
}
```

Comment: add -Verbose to see what is happening foreach.

Comment: I have found the issue. The script took also empty line in csv. I added this condition if ($($_.Name -ne " ") and now it works well.